# Suppressing vibration in Android Notifications using FCM v1 protocol

Tags: android, firebase

I don't see a way in which we can suppress vibrations for system notifications in Android via FCMv1 (i.e notification banners that are shown, including when the app is not running).  I am using [python firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging).

On Android devices, I can choose to suppress sound on notifications on a per app basis, but there is no way to suppress vibrations on a per app basis. The only way for me is to do is to disable vibrations system wide, which is undesirable.

I tried to work around by doing this in my FCM message

- In the SDK, there is an option to *not* follow the default vibrate pattern and set a specific pattern for vibration via an array (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.messaging#androidnotification)). So:
- I set `default_vibrate_timings` to `False`
- And set `vibrate_timings_millis` to `[0,0]`

Hoping that this would result in no vibrations. However, that does not work and the notifications vibrate on the target device. Is there any other way? (I am not really sure if stackoverflow is the best forum for a toolset specific question, but Google [encourages us to ask on StackOverflow](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/fcm))

Comment: Why can't you push notification with the importance set to NotificationManager. IMPORTANCE_LOW?

Comment: IMPORTANCE_LOW also lowers the priority of the message, resulting in some of them not showing at all in the system notification which is not the intent. It needs to be shown, but without vibrations.

Comment: So you want to show the notification even if the user does not want silent notifications to appear in the status bar? In that case you need to send data messages without the notification part and then handle the notification in onMessageReceived(). And do whatever you want

Comment: onMessageReceived() is not invoked if the app is not running. What I want is behavior similar to Android 8 and below - that is, irrespective of whether my app is running or not, when a notification is received, the OS shows the notification in the system tray (Which it does), but the user can choose to disable sound for it on a per app basis (possible via app notification settings) and/or disable vibrate for that app notification (possible in Android 8 and below, but vibration was taken away as an option starting Android 9). The only option seems to be to disable vibrate system wide.

Comment: That's not true. You can get a data message when the app is in the background. You need to implement your own Service and handle the onMessageReceived by yourself. I have done it in the past. I'll post the code

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I implemented a custom FirebaseService:

```
public class AppFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);

        // do something with your token
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            // do what you want
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        }

    }
}
```

and in the manifest add:

```
<service
    android:name=".AppFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Sending a data message, in this case, allows you to keep having the default behaviour for the normal notification

Comment: Thanks - but this will not work if the app is not running - that is, killed. this handler is invoked only if the app is still running (either foreground or background). That's the reason why I can't use data notifications. If the app is killed, then its handler will be called only when it comes back up next.

Comment: Why do you say that it won't work? Push notification will work even if the app is killed